# Is it possible to disconnect all slots from a signal in Qt5 QML?

Tags: qt, qml, signals, disconnect, slot

In QML it is impossible to call `.disconnect()` without arguments for a signal:

```
file:mainwindow.qml:107: Error: Function.prototype.disconnect: no arguments given
```

So how can I disconnect ALL slots without specifying each of them?
Or maybe it is possible by passing signal object to `C++` and disconnect it somehow there?
Or maybe any workaround exists?

The goal I want to reach is to change behavior of an object by connecting different slots to it's signal. For example:

```
object.disconnect() // disconnect all slots
object.connect(one_super_slot)
object.disconnect() // disconnect all slots
object.connect(another_super_slot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, 5 minutes after my question I've made a workaround: connect only once to one signal that calls jsobject from inside:

```
Item {
    property var fire

    // Any qml object. In this example it is ActionExecutor which emits actionRequest
    ActionExecutor {
        //signal actionRequest(int actionType)
        onActionRequest: fire(actionType)
    }

    Action {
        shortcut: "Ctrl+S"
        text: "One action"
        onTriggered: {
            parent.fire = function(actionType) {
                console.log('one slot')
            }
        }
    }

    Action {
        shortcut: "Ctrl+X"
        text: "Another action"
        onTriggered: {
            parent.fire = function(actionType) {
                console.log('Another slot')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that js object can be reassigned many times as you want so you may change your behavior by reassigning this object. If you want to disconnect all simple assign `undefined` to `fire`. Also you can make a chain of "**slots**" by modifying code to something like:

```
Item {
    property var fire
    property var slots: [
        function(actionType) {
            console.log('1: ' + actionType)
        },

        function() {
            console.log('2: ' + actionType)
        },

        function() {
            console.log('3: ' + actionType)
        }
    ]

    // Any qml object. In this example it is ActionExecutor which emits actionRequest
    ActionExecutor {
        //signal actionRequest(int actionType)
        onActionRequest: fire(actionType)
    }

    Action {
        shortcut: "Ctrl+S"
        text: "One action"
        onTriggered: {
            parent.fire = function(actionType) {
                console.log('calling all custom JS-slots')

                for (var i in slots) {
                    slots[i](actionType)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So anyone can implement own signal-slot architecture in qml as a simple javascript observer pattern.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

No. I looked at the source code in `qv4objectwrapper.cpp`, and you can see this code:

```
void QObjectWrapper::initializeBindings(ExecutionEngine *engine)
{
    engine->functionClass->prototype->defineDefaultProperty(QStringLiteral("connect"), method_connect);
    engine->functionClass->prototype->defineDefaultProperty(QStringLiteral("disconnect"), method_disconnect);
}
```

Those are the only two methods that are added. If you look at the source code for `method_disconnect()` you can see that it always requires one or two parameters, including the name of the slot to disconnect.

There is no `disconnectAll()` unfortunately.